# How to connect to websocket FastAPI Socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, fastapi

**ws.py**

```
from loguru import logger
import socketio
from typing import List

def handle_connect(sid, environ):
    logger.info(f"Socket connected with sid {sid}")

class SocketManager:
    def __init__(self, origins: List[str]):
        self.server = socketio.AsyncServer(
            cors_allowed_origins=origins,
            async_mode="asgi",
            logger=True,
            engineio_logger=True,
        )
        self.app = socketio.ASGIApp(self.server)

    @property
    def on(self):
        return self.server.on

    @property
    def send(self):
        return self.server.send

    def mount_to(self, path: str, app: socketio.ASGIApp):
        app.mount(path, self.app)


socket_manager = SocketManager(origins=["*"])
socket_manager.on("connect", handler=handle_connect)
```

**main.py**

```
from ws import socket_manager

app = FastAPI(
    title="MyBackend",
    docs_url="/docs",
    openapi_url="/openapi.json"
)

app.include_router(router, prefix="/api/v1")
socket_manager.mount_to("/ws", app)
```

Getting next error through dev console: **WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:80/ws/' failed**

**In python:**

```
RuntimeError: Expected ASGI message 'websocket.accept' or 'websocket.close', but got 'http.response.start'.
DEBUG:    > HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
DEBUG:    > Upgrade: websocket
DEBUG:    > Connection: Upgrade
DEBUG:    > Sec-WebSocket-Accept: TDJXRnQoVA7XR0L7D7yn+va91Q4=
DEBUG:    > Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
DEBUG:    > date: Sun, 26 Feb 2023 21:04:11 GMT
DEBUG:    > server: uvicorn
INFO:     connection open
DEBUG:    = connection is OPEN
DEBUG:    = connection is CLOSED
DEBUG:    ! failing connection with code 1006
DEBUG:    x half-closing TCP connection
INFO:     connection closed
```

**Whats wrong here and how to fix it?** I understand that WebsocketConnection was expected, but got HttpResponse, but anyway..

Comment: Shot in the dark, but it doesn't look like the server was expecting the establish the connection over HTTP. Sometimes the connection is initiated over HTTP, then "upgraded" to just websockets (for reliability reasons iirc), and that appears to be what the client is doing. Who's the client that's connecting? You may need to configure it to not use HTTP (or configure the server to allow HTTP).

Comment: the client is browser console (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:80/ws/") )

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it can't mount properly. (I had the same issue)

I had fixed it by change the "/ws" to empty string.

Try this:

```
socket_manager.mount_to("", app)
```

and then your url should be:

```
ws://localhost:80/
```

Also, if you'll use websocket for simple things (without any auth mechanism or something) I suggest you to follow **[FastAPI Websocket documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The problem inside `__call__` func in engineio

> ```
> async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
>     if scope['type'] in ['http', 'websocket'] and \
>             scope['path'].startswith(self.engineio_path):
>         await self.engineio_server.handle_request(scope, receive, send)
>     else:
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
>         else:
>             await self.not_found(receive, send)
> ```

It compares path in the scope to the mount point.

You may add `socketio_path` argument to the `socketio.ASGIApp` same like starts from "/ws" and this will work.